# Macbook 2015: Mic sound is not working

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

I am using Catalina. All of a sudden Mic input stopped working and can't record anything. I also tried holding the Shift, Control, Option, and Power keys simultaneously for about 10 seconds, released them, and turned the MacBook on but no difference. This SMC thing did work last time.

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
```

Comment: when you do the reset does the MagSafe plug-light briefly change color ?

Comment: @Ruskes yes it turned green

Comment: Good, so the SMC reset worked, is it external mic ? if so check the plug

Comment: Yes it is external earphone and it works on Mobile

Comment: If you were to disclose all the information upfront we could move faster in the effort to fix it. Is it ear phone with mic is it wireless or wired, what model is it ?  If wireless did you perform new Bluetooth paring ?

Comment: @Ruskes sorry, I am using an earphone...without earphone my input(mic) does not work. I also have added model in main question

Comment: Is your earphone connect with bluetooth (no cable) or with cable

Comment: @Ruskes It was cable-based. It turns out the earphone issue which is strange because the same earphone works with mobile. ANyways.. Thanks for your time